# How to give border to clip path semi circle in flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to add a border to the semi-circle in here

[image]

I am new to flutter, and I'm trying to build a ticket, I found a ticket widget and I also found the below code which looks better than the ticket widget

I was trying semi-circle or arc in the clip-path widget, I got that semi-circle but could not able to give a border to it.

This is what I tried from stack overflow

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart' as v_math;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: MyHomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
      ClipPath(
        clipper: DolDurmaClipper(right: 40, holeRadius: 20),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(15),
            ),
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
          width: 300,
          height: 95,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          child: Text('first example'),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20,
      ),
      ClipPath(
        clipper: DolDurmaClipper(right: 100, holeRadius: 40),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(15),
            ),
            color: Colors.amber,
          ),
          width: 200,
          height: 250,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(35),
          child: Text('second example'),
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}

class DolDurmaClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  DolDurmaClipper({@required this.right, @required this.holeRadius});

  final double right;
  final double holeRadius;

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path()
      ..moveTo(0, 0)
      ..lineTo(size.width - right - holeRadius, 0.0)
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset(size.width - right, 0),
        clockwise: false,
        radius: Radius.circular(1),
      )
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0.0)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width - right, size.height)
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset(size.width - right - holeRadius, size.height),
        clockwise: false,
        radius: Radius.circular(1),
      );

    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);

    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(DolDurmaClipper oldClipper) => true;
}
```

Comment: can you include an image what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please check it, I added an Image now

Comment: try to use this path on shapeBorder or OutlinedBorder

Comment: You mean inside container

Comment: yes, you can use it on any `shape`

Comment: not working, can you try and forward me your code please

Comment: I am not able to perfectly central the middle grey rect, you can override customPaint